# using console.log to show value in object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an array of objects like this:

```
Object {index: "4", value: -1} 
Object {index: "0", value: 0} 
Object {index: "6", value: 0} 
Object {index: "8", value: 0} 
Object {index: "1", value: 1} 
Object {index: "3", value: 1} 
Object {index: "5", value: 1} 
Object {index: "7", value: 1}
```

The very first one has an index of 0 and I can access it like `console.log[array[0]` which will give me `Object {index: "4", value: -1}` now what if instead of using an index of the object array I wanted to access it by the `value` or `index` inside the object itself. I have tried several different commands like.

```
console.log(array["index: " + 8]
console.log(array["index:" == 8]
```

none of these are doing anything except throwing undefined or errors for the two examples above I wanted them to print out `Object {index: "8", value: 0}` I hope this makes sense

Comment: `console.log[array[0]` is all kinds of broken syntax.

Comment: I'm afraid JavaScript doesn't work this way. You'll need to search and/or loop the array some how in order to do this.

Comment: You need to write a small function to loop the array to find an element, or use an external library like jQuery. jQuery has function `.inArray` . There are a few examples here in SO

Comment: It's legitmately a question, but i think a quick skim through w3c's javascript tutorials and you'll see why your code will not work.

Comment: `console.log(array[0])` works perfectly fine I mistyped in the question

Comment: @Yamaha32088 "Serial downvoting reversed" nice try though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript's [property accessors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators) can't look within the `Object`s being held by an `Array` to apply a condition against them.

The closest option to that is probably [`.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

```
var filtered = array.filter(function (item) {
    return item.index === "8";
});

console.log(filtered[0]); // Object {index: "8", value: 0}
```

You can also use a [`for` loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for) and [`if` test](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else) to find it.

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>[**fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/VCh7v/)</kbd>

```
function find_index(x) {
    var y = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (arr[i].index == x) {
            y = arr[i];
            break;
        }
    }
    return y;
}
console.log(find_index(8)); //Object {index: "8", value: 0}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing to do with `8` here. This is not at all how you work with objects in JavaScript, as even the most basic tutorial would show you.

Given `obj = {index: "4", value: -1}`, you can access the two values with `obj.index` or `obj.value`. You can't invent some `"index: == 8"` weirdness and expect sane results.

```
obj = {index: "4", value: -1}

console.log(obj.index) // 4
console.log(obj.value) // -1
```

If you want to find an object that has an index of 8, that involves sequentially scanning the array with a loop, not writing some pseudo-query language.